# Как соотнести размер картинки и окна программы в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, форма

Привет всем.

Просьба не переносить, пожалуйста, тему в другой раздел.

Есть картинка предположим 500x300px (ИСП. Пиксели).
Есть форма в Visual Studio. Сделана в конструкторе через WinAPI.

Суть в том, что в студии же используются размеры в DIP. А моя картинка в пикселях.

Картинку нужно запилить на button. Да и саму форму нужно представить в пикселях. Чтобы всё ровно было.

Как вот с этим справиться?

---

Если не понятно сказал:
В ФШ нарисовали дизайн проги. Разбили его на отдельные картинки(для вставок в кнопки и тд).
Как установить размер формы в конструкторе правильно, чтобы размеры картинок(px) и формы(dip) совпадали?

На скрине форма 500x300, но она чуть ли не в 2 раза больше, чем картинка, которая тоже 500x300[image: введите сюда описание изображения]